# Redirect is not working in cakephp after registration

Tags: php, cakephp

```
function signup(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){


        if(isset($this->data['User']['password2']))
            $this->data['User']['password2hashed'] = $this->
            Auth->password($this->data['User']['password2']);
        $this->User->create();
        if($this->User->save($this->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Congratulatios, you have signed up');
            $this->redirect('updateProfile');

        }
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('There was an error signing up, Please try again later');
            $this->data= null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me, what am I doing wrong, I am new to cakephp, thanks

Comment: You have syntax errors. `Auth->password` has dropped a line from where it should be and you have `} {` with no `else` or another `if` statement

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @ scrowler, I did what you said, but it is still the samething

Comment: @Bharat Maheshwari, i do not get any error, after updating the database, it just redirect to the login form, instead of the updateProfile that I specified in the redirect method

Comment: do you have any login check on updateProfile() function or is it in $this->Auth->allow() ?

Comment: Have you try by this line ?
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'updateProfile'));

Comment: i just created an action in my user controller, infact, I have not set auth allow, do i need to add $this->Athh->Allow? if yes , where?

Comment: It should be $this->redirect('/updateProfile') or best way $this->redirect(array('action' => 'updateProfile')); @user2090999

Comment: what is updateProfile? if it is a function then use array('action' => 'updateProfile') in redirect.

Comment: Most likely if you check what's happening you _are_ being redirected (to the wrong url) and then redirected again to login or something like that - you need to debug for yourself and find out/clarify

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to set return before redirection

```
 return $this->redirect(
            array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'updateProfile')
        );
```

[More info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aredirect)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->redirect('updateProfile'); //this is wrong
```

it must be:

```
 return $this->redirect("/users/updateProfile");
```

or:

```
 return $this->redirect("updateProfile");
```